# Getting variable from Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I am doing something very simple yet ... I can't figure it out. I created an extension that all it does is get a variable. I want to be able access that variable from my web page. Any thoughts?

A little background why I'm doing this. I needed to have chrome access to get this variable which is why I made this extension in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at this link: [Interaction between privileged and non-privileged pages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/Interaction_between_privileged_and_non-privileged_pages) for some code-samples on sending data from chrome (priveleged) to unprivileged document (webpage).

In the extension:

```
var myExtension =
{
  myListener: function(evt)
  {
    alert("Received from web page: " + 
           evt.target.getAttribute("attribute1") + "/" +
           evt.target.getAttribute("attribute2"));

/* the extension answers the page*/
    evt.target.setAttribute("attribute3", "The extension");

    var doc = evt.target.ownerDocument;

    var AnswerEvt = doc.createElement("MyExtensionAnswer");
    AnswerEvt.setAttribute("Part1", "answers this.");

    doc.documentElement.appendChild(AnswerEvt);

    var event = doc.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
    event.initEvent("MyAnswerEvent", true, false);
    AnswerEvt.dispatchEvent(event);
  }
}

document.addEventListener("MyExtensionEvent", function(e) { myExtension.myListener(e); }, false, true);
// The last value is a Mozilla-specific value to indicate untrusted content is allowed to trigger the event.
```

In the web-page:

```
document.addEventListener("MyAnswerEvent",function(e) { ExtensionAnswer(e); },false);

var element;

function CallExtension()
{
  var element = document.createElement("MyExtensionDataElement");
  element.setAttribute("attribute1", "foobar");
  element.setAttribute("attribute2", "hello world");
  document.documentElement.appendChild(element);
  var evt = document.createEvent("Events");
  evt.initEvent("MyExtensionEvent", true, false);
  element.dispatchEvent(evt);
}

function ExtensionAnswer(EvtAnswer)
{
  alert(element.getAttribute("attribute3") + " " +
        EvtAnswer.target.getAttribute("Part1"));
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well this doesn't really help me. All I am trying to do is pass a variable (which is already saved in my extension when the browser is started) to my webpage when it is loaded up. Ex. So i'm thinking I would have to have some sort of messenger listener in my extension, and when my webpage loads it will request the variable and the message listener will then in turn send it to my webpage where it will be saved and used.

Comment: the link I referred to also has a example how to send data from unprivileged document to chrome. Together they might form a 2-way communication, but I'll admit, I never personally tried this.